# Fetching a html page dynamically and animating it - jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to fetch a html page and display it with a fadeIn animation...
But the fetching doesn't work and due to this even the animation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var src;

    $.ajax({
        url: "pages/sample.html",
        success: function (data) { src=data },
        dataType: 'html'
     });

    console.log(src);   **// Throws undefined**

    //To animate
    $(function() {
        $('html')
            .hide()
            .html(src)
            .fadeIn(5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: put console.log in a function and call that func with data as param in the success callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ajax` is an **async** operation, meaning it will return in the future.
Enter the code that uses the return value inside the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pages/sample.html",
    success: function (data) { 
                 src=data ;
                 console.log(src);
            },
    dataType: 'html'
 });
```

Comment: @user1184100. just remember **ajax** is for "**Asynchronous** JavaScript And XML"

Answer (score 1):

Use `.load()` instead of `ajax()` something like:

```
$('#result').load('pages/sample.html', function() {
  //animation goes here
});
```

for more info visit [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: he uses the data outside the callback. that's his problem.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is a asynchronous operation, meaning that you cannot expect the result to be available at once, but some time in the future. jQuery provides the ability to use a callback, which is called, as soon as the result is available.
You have to modify your code a little bit:

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "pages/sample.html",
        success: function (data) { ajaxDataArrived(data); },
        dataType: 'html'
     });

    function ajaxDataArrived (src) {
        console.log(src);
        $("html").hide().html(src).fadeIn(5000);
    }

});
```

Please note, that there is a specific function for loading HTML content in jQuery: [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). It works slightly different than the code example above, since jQuery handles the callback for you:

```
$("html").load("pages/sample.html");
```

This will load and automatically insert the content, as soon as it's loaded.
You can provide a callback for this function too, but it is called *after* the code is inserted. So this might not work in your case, since you want to hide the html before inserting it. I just wanted to add it for the sake of completeness.